# Splitting up a Flask application?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a large-ish Flask project (using Flask-SQLAlchemy) which has a `core` component which involves processing a large amount of data and then saving the results to a database. It has its own set of Flask-SQLAlchemy models for this.

There is also a `web` component which defines a Flask app for the API and another Flask app for the web front end, both of which present the results of the `core` component's processing. The `web` part also defines some of its own models (User models) which the `core` component has no need for.

For the ease of development and organization, I want to split out the `core` component into a separate project and keep the `web` parts in their own project. The two components are already fairly separated so it should be a straightforward process.

The only part I can't figure out is: how does the `web` component get access to the `core` components' models? I don't want to have to duplicate the model definitions across both projects.

Comment: Could you not create a python package for the core with a setup.py and install this in to each of the web components?

Comment: That's the approach I was considering, but couldn't wrap my head around a good way to deal with database migrations. What happens if any of the `core` package models change? I'll take another shot at it, thanks.

Comment: If that's the case and they both use exactly the same core why not have an internal API which the API and web frontend call? Either that or make the web frontend use your API frontend

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want to look at Flask's [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/) which will allow you to modularise your code as you've described whilst allowing you to also inherit some core stuff such as your SQLAlchemy Models.

Comment: Updated version number in link: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/